# How does Singleton pattern stay in memory throughout the lifetime of the program?

Tags: php, scope, singleton

I have the following code:

```
//init X (DB initialization with credentials)
$x = MySqlConnector::getMySql();

//I destroy $x
unset($x);
$x = null;

//I try to re-initialize the database, but it is already initialized
//as evident from my logs
$x = MySqlConnector::getMySql();
```

Relevant function:

```
public static function getMySql()
{
    if (null === static::$instance)
    {
        include 'include/config.php';
        static::$instance = new MySql(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    }

    return static::$instance;
}
```

That tells me that even after I kill off the variable that was holding the initialized object, somehow `MySqlConnector` stayed in memory.

How? I don't think it works with any other non-static class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static properties exist in the global scope, and are not associated to any particular instance.

You may be unsetting `$x`, but `MySqlConnector::$instance` stays defined.

Typically, in this kind of scenario, `$instance` will be a `private static`, so you wont be able to access the property directly, only through accesor methods, hence guaranteeing that only the Singleton class will have access to modify the property, and you wont be changing/setting/unsetting it but through properly defined methods, if they exist.

More info in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).